# Variance of forecast's error

Tags: variance

Is there any situation in which

$$\text{var}(d_t-f_t)=\text{var}(d_t)+\text{var}(f_t)-\text{cov}(d_t,f_t)$$

can be used instead of

$$\text{var}(dt-ft)=\text{var}(d_t)+\text{var}(f_t)-2\text{cov}(d_t,f_t)$$

where $d_t$ is a times series and $f_t$ is it's forecast.

thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -ab$ ? it is true only when a or b is zero. Your first formula is true only when cov(dt, ft)=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second expression above is a mathematical identity, so no, your first expression is not valid in any situation apart from when cov(dt,ft)=0 (which appears highly unlikely in the context you give).